# add section to toc with number

Tags: table-of-contents

I have some scanned pdf documents which I want to put together in a latex file and structure them with sections which appear only in the TOC. This has the advantage, that I can jump to the page using hyperref.

However with this code only text is added to the toc, but I would like them to be numbered as if I had written a normal \section.

```
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{SI-System}
\includepdf[pages=1-3,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{02-SI.pdf}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `addtotoc` option for the `\includepdf` command; this option has the syntax

```
addtotoc={<page number>,<section>,<level>,<heading>,<label>}
```

where `<page number>` is the page number of the inserted document that will be linked to from the ToC, `<section>` is the LaTeX sectioning name (e.g., section, subsection,...), `<level>` denotes depth of section (e.g., 1 for section level, 2 for
subsection level,...), `<heading>` is the title inserted in the table of contents, and `<label>` is the name of the label which can be referred to with `\ref` and
`\pageref`.

With your current approach you can use `\numberline` to add the number of the corresponding sectional unit to the ToC; for example, you can say something like:

```
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}SI-System}
```

Here's an example or the use of addtotoc option (kindly provided by **Marco Daniel**):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-a5.tex}
\documentclass[english,paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname-a5.tex}
\usepackage{pdfpages,lipsum}
\includepdfset{frame,noautoscale}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{foo}
\lipsum[1]
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,section,1,Eintrag im Inhaltsverzeichnis,mylabel}]{\jobname-a5}
\end{document}
```

save the file as, for example, `test.tex` and run it using

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test
```

Comment: addtotoc does not work for me because I do not know the pagenumber and `\protect\numberline{\thechapter}` adds a number, but that is always 0, since there is nothing which could change it.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: but you can always use `1` for `<page number>`; this way, the first page of the included document will be linked from the ToC.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the meaning of the 'number'

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now by defining the numbering myself:

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \addtocounter{chapter}{1}
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  \addtocounter{section}{1}
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}
    {\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}
}
```

and using these redefined chapter and section commands.

Comment: Please delete you answer. Such hack isn't a qualified answer.

Comment: Then please provide something better. The other answer does not provide any numbering and all I did was to extent that approach by numbering the sections automatically.

Comment: I will provide an example which uses the command `addtotoc`.

Comment: The page number of `addtotoc` is the number of the page which will be linked.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I add > 50 pdfs, all with different page counts. The number must be inserted automatically, otherwise the addtotoc is no option for me.

Comment: In German: `addtotoc` ist unabhängig der Seitenzahl. Bitte schaue dir das Beispiel oben an. In English (not so good): `addtotoc` is independently from the page numbers of the including pdf. For the including pages you can use the option `pages` furthermore. The page number is normally 1 so the link goes the the first included site.

Comment: Note that line-endings are taken as spaces, so you should end lines which do not end with a control sequence (i.e. a macro, which ignores spaces afterwards) with a `%`. I mean all lines ending with `{` and `}`.