# Table of contents of included pdf

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, labels, pdfpages, include

How can I do a table of contents, list of figures and list of tables of included pdf

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

\include{Chapter1/chapter01}
\includepdf[pages=1-19]{./Chapter2/Article1.pdf}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this question help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38409/add-section-to-toc-with-number

Comment: The `addtotoc` and `addtolist` options of `pdfpages` (as shown in the above linked question) will definitely do what you want. I didn't know they existed until then, but it's a neat idea.

Comment: @DavidPurton, Thank you for the link. I tried to use this idea, but if I have several sections in a page, for example in the first page, I only have a section but in the third page, I have a section, two subsections and one figure,... 
Please, how can I do it using this link!

Comment: If Article1.pdf was created using LaTeX and you still have the aux file, you can use \externaldocument from the xr package/ Otherwise, the information has been lost and will have to be added by hand.  Of course, it would use the original page numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `addtotoc` and `addtolist` options of the `pdfpages` package to specify a full document structure and list of tables and figures.

You will get hyperlinks to the page rather than exact location on the page, but that's not the end of the world. (You could do this, but not in as automatic a way.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\include{Chapter1/chapter01}

\includepdf[%
  pages=1-19,
  addtotoc={
    1,chapter,0,Article 1,A1-1,
    2,section,1,First Section of Article 1,A1-2,
    2,section,1,Second Section of Article 1,A1-3
  },
  addtolist={
    3,figure,First Figure of Article 1,A1-4,
    3,figure,Second Figure of Article 1,A1-5,
    4,table,First Table of Article 1,A1-6
  }
]{./Chapter2/Article1.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!, do you know please how to add  to TOC an unnumbered section or an appendix.

Comment: @Achaire, not off the top of my head. I suggest you ask a new question referencing this one with an appropriate MWE that people can test with.

Comment: @Achaire, calling `\appendix` before inserting your pages allows for appendixes.